# Cannot get 3D model with texture to display correct

Tags: ios, 3d, textures, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I "trying" to learn OpenGL using the book "Learning OpenGL ES for iOS: A Hands-on Guide to Modern 3D Graphics Programming by Erik M. Buck"

I have got to the stage where I am trying to load a 3D model in a tester app to confirm my knowledge and although I can get the model displayed it appears reversed and the texture seems part displayed (or displayed incorrectly).

I have tried GL_BLEND, GL_DEPTH_TEST, using ortho not using ortho to no avail and realise I'm probably missing something integral..thinking it might be something to do with face normals?

here is what should appear:

[image]

and this is what I get:

[image]
can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Is this really a texture?  It looks like a backface culling problem to me.  Try disabling that, and try reversing the winding direction that is considered back facing.

Comment: Not sure, what I have done is used a sphere obj data in the book example to see what results I get and it displays the earth with texture applied as in the book.  So I "think" I am doing it right otherwise the earth sphere would not display correct?  Weird.  I am basically taking the example app which I have re-written and replaced the earth sphere obj with the molecule object.  I have also tried it with another of the book examples that uses a 3d model that can be rotated, translated and scaled etc and the example works fine but when I try to bring in my own object I get this kind of display?

Comment: I can post the project if it helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the book looked at this for me and found out the following:

The .obj model was produced using "quads", 4 sided polygons, but OpenGL ES can only render points, lines, and triangles. As a result, only half (1 triangle) of each quad was rendered.

Opening the .obj file in Blender and exporting using triangles resulted in the correct display appearing.

Thanks to Erik Buck for taking the time to help one of his readers and thanks too to @clayMontgomery for his assistance ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the code for your sphere model assumes that backface culling is either disabled or requires the opposite winding direction (clock-wise or counter-clock wise) for its triangle strips.  You should try to initialize OpenGL ES correctly for what that code expects.  I would try this:

```
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
```

OR

```
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
```

OR

```
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
```

For more information, see "Polygon Details" in the OpenGL Red Book, chapter 2:

```
http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter02.html
```

Comment: Hi, really appreciate your help thank you!  I tried your suggestions and there is some improvement in that at least the colours seem to being applied to the correct part of model. this is with cull face disabled [IMG]http://i41.tinypic.com/2i9366x.jpg[/IMG] and this is using frontface cw [IMG]http://i41.tinypic.com/fk19hk.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: I see the sphere is expecting a glFrustumf or glOrthof coordinate system.  so using ortho like so   self.baseEffect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(-0.5 * aspectRatio, 0.5 * aspectRatio, -0.5f, 0.5, -5.0, 5.0); gives this [IMG]http://i43.tinypic.com/2a6ozds.jpg[/IMG]